Testing if some random looking desimal number is function of irrational numbers
let's say I have some ten digit random-looking decimal number, such as 1.4076961940. I would be interested of seeing if that decimal number could be approximation of some kind of function of most common irrational numbers, such as 9 × π ÷ (e^3). I understand there is infinite possibilities to construct this kind of function of common irrational numbers, but scanning some "simple" possible relations would be enough.
I am relatively illiterate with mathematics, but I would guess limiting to simple cases could be estimated with some program. Are there some automatic lookup tables or online "calculators" for such task? Or maybe some Python codes?

An approximation like that might be useless unless there is actually some relationship. $\pi$ and $e$ are also meaningless constant numbers depending on the context. Although they have meaning in some cases, if you are just using them as constant numbers then in your case it is just meaningless unless they are actually related to the random ten-digit number. But the value of $\pi$ and $e$ is about 3.14 and 2.71, so knowing this that's all you need to create your functions. Because it seems like you are just creating functions for the value, if there's not a relationship, it's meaningless.

To explain my previous comment, you might just be fooling yourself if you are looking for something like your examples, because that doesn't tell you anything of value. You may as well just substitute them for 3.14 and 2.71. To me it seems like you're trying to express numbers as a relationship of significant numbers, but if it's just coincidental than what's the point?

Thanks for your answer. I do agree that this would be useless in most of the cases and one would easily fool themselves to believe there is relationship. This would be interesting nevertheless.

There used to be an online tool for this, the Inverse Symbolic Calculator. This is defunct, but if you are a code geek, you can try RIES.

Thanks TonyK! Inverse Symbolic Calculator seems to be exactly what I am lookin for. Unfortunately it does not work anymore. RIES seems a bit hard for me, but I'll check it.
